# Proper way to give parameters with a contract call?

Tags: contract-invocation

I am trying to do a contract call with some parameters. I do this with a NodeJS Express API.

The code looks as following:

```
var array = JSON.parse(req.body.arguments);
                getContractFromABIAndAddress(req.body.abi, req.body.contractAddress, function(contract) {
                    contract.methods[req.body.method](array).send({from: config.publickey}).on('receipt', function(receipt) {
                        res.json({
                            txHash: receipt.transactionHash,
                            contractAddress: receipt.contractAddress,
                            txURL: config.etherscantransaction + receipt.transactionHash,
                            contractURL: config.etherscanaddress + receipt.contractAddress
                        })
                    });
                })
```

The `req.body.arguments` contains the needed parameters and the `req.body.method` contains the right method to call on the contract.

I can test the code with postman, the body would look like the following picture.

[image: Image of post with postman]

Now as you can see here: [Web3 Contract docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12),
I am using the second option. `myContract.methods['myMethod(uint256)'](123)`

The problem is that I can't send multiple parameters, the contract needs the parameters like this: `myContract.methods['myMethod(uint256,uint256)'](2,2)` but I am giving them like this `myContract.methods['myMethod(uint256,uint256)']([2,2])`.

This results in the following: [image]

Which means that the contract call is only getting one parameter according to the error logs and to the web3-eth-contract library. This can be solved by doing the following: [image]

Which turns my parameters back to the right format: [image]

If the Web3 library would get an update now, my NodeJS API wouldn't work anymore because I have been messing with the library. I can't find any other way to give the parameters with the contract call, or with contract send, since the problem also exists over there.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
contract.methods[req.body.method].apply(contract, array)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply.

Comment: Then `contract.methods[req.body.method]` is undefined... that problem seems unrelated to the use of `apply`. Make sure that `req.body.method` is the name of a method that actually exists on the contract. (**EDIT**: This was in response to a comment that has since been deleted.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

However, this is not the solution for me.
I now get the following error: `Error: Invalid number of parameters for &quot;myMethod&quot;. Got undefined expected 2!`

Code is looking as follows: 
`contract.methods[req.body.method].apply(contract, array).send({from: config.publickey}).on('receipt', function(receipt) {`

Comment: Did you remove your change to `web3-eth-contract`?

Comment: Sorry, it has been a very long day haha. Thank you so much!